# What subject teaches derivation of trigonometric identities?

Tags: integration, soft-question

I'm a college student. In order to ace my single-variable calculus course, I have memorized many trigonometric formulas including

$$\int \sin^m x \cos^n x dx = \frac{\sin^{m+1} x \cos^{n-1}x}{m+n} + \frac{n-1}{m+n} \int \sin^m x \cos^{n-2}x dx$$

I want to learn how to derive these formulas, so what course or courses will teach me how to derive these formulas?
Or am I supposed to learn the derivations indepently (i.e. instead of learning a course, I just have to look up individual derivations on the internet) My guess is that the answer is some kind of analysis course, but I really have no idea.

Comment: http://calc101.com/deriving_reduction.html  I think in question there should be $\cos^nx$

Comment: should I delete my question?

Comment: no this is not necessasry

Comment: this is called reduction formula in integral

Comment: There isn't a course in which will learn specifically about these things. Such identities only come up as exercises and are not of particular significance. You'll have to find'em independently. Despite this, there are some courses which are more prone to have such problems show up, I'd say calculus courses (non-vector calculus) and analytic number theory courses. The user [Chris's sister](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/32016/chriss-wise-sister) might have some of those for you in his/her questions and you could even perhaps ping him/her, he might know where you can find such problems.

Comment: Repeating some comments.  Such things come up in integral calculus courses, as application of "integration by parts".  Git says "not or particular significance" ... maybe or maybe not (since it can be done by a CAS faster than by a mathematician).  But such problems are certainly useful in getting the student some feeling for integration by parts (which is important in applications).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These type of recursion formulas for parameter depending primitives are dealt by (usually) integrating by parts.

Write $$I(m,n)=\int {{{\sin }^m}} x{\cos ^n}xdx = \int {{{\sin }^m}} x{\cos ^{n - 1}}x\cos xdx = \int {{{\sin }^m}} x{\cos ^{n - 1}}xd\left( {\sin x} \right)$$

and integrate by parts with $$du=\sin^mxd(\sin x)$$$$ v=\cos^{n-1}x$$

Then $$I(m,n)=\frac{\sin^{m+1}x}{m+1}\cos^{n-1}x+\frac{n-1}{m+1}\int\cos^{n-2}x\sin^{m+2} xdx$$

Now write $\sin^{m+2}x=\sin^m x\sin^2x$ and use that $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$. Then $$\begin{align}
   I(m,n) &= \frac{{{{\sin }^{m + 1}}x}}{{m + 1}}{\cos ^{n - 1}}x + \frac{{n - 1}}{{m + 1}}\int {{{\cos }^{n - 2}}} x{\sin ^m}xdx - \frac{{n - 1}}{{m + 1}}\int {{{\cos }^n}} x{\sin ^m}xdx  \\
   I(m,n) &= \frac{{{{\sin }^{m + 1}}x}}{{m + 1}}{\cos ^{n - 1}}x + \frac{{n - 1}}{{m + 1}}\int {{{\cos }^{n - 2}}} x{\sin ^m}xdx - \frac{{n - 1}}{{m + 1}}I(m,n)  \\ 
   \left( {\frac{{m + n}}{{m + 1}}} \right)I(m,n) &= \frac{{{{\sin }^{m + 1}}x}}{{m + 1}}{\cos ^{n - 1}}x + \frac{{n - 1}}{{m + 1}}\int {{{\cos }^{n - 2}}} x{\sin ^m}xdx  \\ 
   I(m,n) &= \frac{{{{\sin }^{m + 1}}x}}{{m + n}}{\cos ^{n - 1}}x + \frac{{n - 1}}{{m + n}}\int {{{\cos }^{n - 2}}} x{\sin ^m}xdx \end{align}$$